# Motor returning None

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, motordriver, tornado-motor

I am using Motor driver to connect to Mongo DB.
Below is the code to insert data to the collection

```
  client = motor.MotorClient('mongodb://localhost:27017').open_sync()
  conn = client['database']['collection']
  result = conn.insert({'foo': 'bar'}) 
  print 'result:', result
```

The insert statement always returns None.
This is not a Tornado application.
Can motor be only used with Tornado?
If not why is the insert returning none?

Answer (score 2):

You use motor just like pymongo. But motor is asynchronous: it means that when your print is executed, maybe the db request is not finished yet.
Furthermore, motor insert does not return anything, and you need to use a callback function as second argument with it. Cf. [the differences between pymongo and motor](http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/differences.html), and  [the motor tutorial on how to insert a document](http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#inserting-a-document).

In your case, the good way of soing this would be:

```
client = motor.MotorClient('mongodb://localhost:27017').open_sync()
conn = client['database']['collection']
result = conn.insert({'foo': 'bar'}, callback=once_done) 

def once_done(result, error):
    if error: print 'error:', error
    else:
        print 'result:', result
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the WriteConcern is not set from the client-driver.

If you set it as safe=true, then you will get the status of the insert operation. Otherwise with safe=false, the insert operation is fire and forget.

You can try:

```
motor.MotorClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/?safe=true')
```

Comment: Then I guess, this is not the correct way of specifying the WriteConcern in Motor drive client.

But you can check for setting the write concern in motor cleint : http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/motor_client.html#motor.MotorClient.write_concern